# AJAX error ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES, how to avoid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried researching about this matter, and I know that this error occurs because of too many ajax calls that's why the browser can't handle it. However I think that the solution is a case to case. Let me try to explain on how this code works

First I select a csv file (8000 rows) then I will upload it to the database, the calling function works like this.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-group-agent-upload", function () {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    updateUploadPercentage(0);

    var file = $("#group-agent-file").prop("files")[0];

    reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');

    reader.onload = Insert_Bulk_Agent;

});
```

and it execute the function `Insert_Bulk_Agent` in which this

```
function Insert_Bulk_Agent(event) {

var result = event.target.result;
var data = $.csv.toObjects(result);
var length = data.length;
var count = 0;
var arrayCollection = [];
var tbody = $("#error-list").find("tbody");
if (length > 0) {

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {

        if(val.AgentStatus == "" || val.BirthDate == "" || val.CSP == "" || val.Classification == "" || val.ContactNumber == "" ||
            val.EmailAddress == "" || val.FirstName == "" || val.LastName == "" || val.MiddleName == "" || val.LiveDate == "" || val.Program == "") {
            $.ajax({
                success: function () {
                    //console.log('ok');

                    $(tbody).append("<tr><td>" + val.FirstName + ' ' + val.MiddleName + ' ' + val.LastName + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + val.Tool + "</td></tr>");
                    arrayCollection.push(val);
                    count = count + 1;
                    var percentageCompleted = count / length * 100;
                    updateUploadPercentage(parseInt(percentageCompleted));

                }
            });
        } else {

            $.ajax({
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (evt) {
                        count = count + 1;
                        var percentageCompleted = count / length * 100;
                        updateUploadPercentage(parseInt(percentageCompleted));

                    };
                    return xhr;
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: "IROA_StoredProcedures.asmx/Insert_Bulk_Agent",
                data: JSON.stringify(val),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {


                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {

                    count = count + 1;
                    var percentageCompleted = count / length * 100;
                    updateUploadPercentage(parseInt(percentageCompleted));
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(val));
                }

            });

        }    
    });

}
else {

    alert("The selected file is empty");

}
 Update_uam();
}
```

**First**
   The function loop through each row and evaluates if the required fields are not `null` or `""` value. If it is the function then add a row in a `html` table. If it has values it will then call an ajax that will insert the values to the database. Now the issue is it's having problem because of multiple `AJAX` calls. How can I handle this error?

**Second**
   There is another function that wiill call here `update_uam` is it sure that this function will execute after all the `Insert_Bulk_Agent` process?

Comment: so, you're kicking off 8000 ajax requests all at once?

Comment: yes. It depends on the file. But I tested it with 8000 rows. So its 8000 ajax request

Comment: The concept of triggering 8000+ requests should be reviewed. The final objective sure can be achieved another way. Relying on the client to mass query infos is a definitive **Don't do!**.

Comment: You need to, obviously, limit the number of simultaneous requests. See if [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/h1mndd7z/) helps - though, I agree there must be a better way than 8000 requests, either simultaneous or not - the code in the fiddle will probably take a LOOOONG time anyway

Comment: Go for less than 4~5 ajax request at once... Very less... ONE should do! Hey do you think mobile a bit? Your concept is an abomination in this view.

Comment: @JaromandaX your code works and I think the speed is great. The difference is not that long. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. And if you have time can you please explain as much as you can on your available time. Thank you

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yeah it's a rookie mistake so please give me a break :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, here is a "multiple" queue I wrote (but never tested in production, so thanks for being the guinea pig :p )

This allows you to have a single "queue" to add Promises to, and they will end up in `max` parallel queues - perfect for limiting the number of concurrent ajax requests. `$.ajax` by the way, returns a Promise

Now, this is primitive, in that any error in one of the queue's will halt that queue, so it probably needs more to be properly useful

```
const multiQueue = max => {
    max = (isNaN(max) || max < 1) ? 1 : max;
    const q = new Array(max).fill(0).map(() => Promise.resolve());
    let index = 0;
    const add = (cb, ...args) => {
        index = (index + 1) % max;
        return (q[index] = q[index].then(() => cb(...args)));
    };
    return add;
};
```

> I just had a quick think, and possibly

```
return (q[index] = q[index].then(() => cb(...args)
    .then(data => ({data}))
    .catch(error => ({error}))
);
```

> *may* make the queues less fragile, note that all promises would then resolve to either `{data: whatever the resolved result was}` or `{error: whatever the rejection reason was}`

The changes to your code are minimal

```
Promise.all(data.map((val, key) => {
    // inside the map function
})).then(Update_uam);
```

This will wait until all the Promises (ajax) are complete, then call `Update_uam`

*inside the map function* for either case of the condition

```
return queue(() => $.ajax({
    // ajax request
}));
```

returns the promise returned by `$.ajax` which has been added to the queue

So, the whole code is:

```
var queue = multiQueue(6); // most browsers I think limit to 6 simultaneous AJAX anyway

function Insert_Bulk_Agent(event) {

    var result = event.target.result;
    var data = $.csv.toObjects(result);
    var length = data.length;
    var count = 0;
    var arrayCollection = [];
    var tbody = $("#error-list").find("tbody");
    if (length > 0) {
        Promise.all(data.map((val, key) => {
            if (val.AgentStatus == "" || val.BirthDate == "" || val.CSP == "" || val.Classification == "" || val.ContactNumber == "" ||
                val.EmailAddress == "" || val.FirstName == "" || val.LastName == "" || val.MiddleName == "" || val.LiveDate == "" || val.Program == "") {
                return queue(() => $.ajax({
                    success: function() {
                        //console.log('ok');

                        $(tbody).append("<tr><td>" + val.FirstName + ' ' + val.MiddleName + ' ' + val.LastName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + val.Tool + "</td></tr>");
                        arrayCollection.push(val);
                        count = count + 1;
                        var percentageCompleted = count / length * 100;
                        updateUploadPercentage(parseInt(percentageCompleted));

                    }
                }));
            } else {
                return queue(() => $.ajax({
                    xhr: function() {
                        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt) {
                            count = count + 1;
                            var percentageCompleted = count / length * 100;
                            updateUploadPercentage(parseInt(percentageCompleted));

                        };
                        return xhr;
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "IROA_StoredProcedures.asmx/Insert_Bulk_Agent",
                    data: JSON.stringify(val),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function() {


                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {

                        count = count + 1;
                        var percentageCompleted = count / length * 100;
                        updateUploadPercentage(parseInt(percentageCompleted));
                        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(val));
                    }

                }));
            }
        })).then(Update_uam);

    } else {
        alert("The selected file is empty");
        Update_uam();
    }
}
```

Comment: A great answer. But what if the const is not supported on the browser. will using var is fine?

Comment: run this through babel - https://babeljs.io/repl/ - you end up with https://jsfiddle.net/h1mndd7z/1/

Comment: I used polyfill to use the fill function. But I am having an error at `promise.resolved()` it says promise is undefined

Comment: `promise.resolved` - you mean `Promise.resolve` ? capital P, no "d"?

Comment: yes sorry, thats typo. It seems that the promise is not supported in IE10.

Comment: However after referencing `Bluebird` `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.5/bluebird.min.js"></script>` I can run the app.

Comment: Thank you for this. i will study this code more. Cause there is so many code in here that I don't understand.

Comment: Really? What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using IE10 and it seems IE does not support promise

Comment: there are polyfills other than Bluebird for Promises :p But I see your point :p

Comment: what are you using for these?

Comment: A browser other than IE10 :p - seriously though, Bluebird is a good choice. I've written my own, which I use

Comment: can you share yours? so I can see it?

Comment: Why? Bluebird is Promise/A+ compliant, as is mine, as are many may Promise libraries - https://promisesaplus.com/implementations - look up Promise3 in that list, I found that one to be particularly easy to read