# javascript - proper way to do thousands of $.getJSON calls to avoid ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCE

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

**Problems**:

I'm doing some data lookup from a website contain thousands of `.json` files, now I'm reading those .json with a straight forward for loop `$.getJSON` calls. It works fine within ~3000 files, but when the size goes up to 5000 or even 20000 (max number I've to read). The Chrome browser becomes super slow or get `ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCE`.

**What I'm doing right now:**

1. scan through data `example.org/1.json` to `20000.json`
2. read these `.json` content into `arrayone[]`, process array of data captured
3. based on `arrayone[]`, I do another `$.getJSON` on `example.org/someplace/1.json` to `20000.json`
4. read these `.json` content into `arraytwo[]`
5. compare `arrayone[]` & `arraytwo[]`

So given I've to read 20000 files, it's actually 40000 `$.getJSON` call.

**Seek helps:**

Is there a smarter way to read multiple `.json` with better performance?
Hope it's clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the backend in your control? If so, you could just expose a better endpoint that returns more than one file at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! No. It's a public website owned by others, I only have access to client side.

Comment: Do you have to process all data simultaneously? If not, could you chunk it into smaller parts (ie batches of each 1000 files)? In other words, do you need all n.json in the same array, or is this not really necessary?

Comment: If aaa.com is just an example domain, I'd suggest to use http://example.org/1.json instead (and avoid unecessary traffic for the aaa.com domain)

Comment: Let's say I have 3000 .json need to be read into arrayone[], would it be quicker if I run 3 times $getJSON (1-1000), (1001-2000), (2001-3000) asynchronously vs. $getJSON 1-3000? Sounds possibly a workaround, could have a try, thanks.

Comment: You can also take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436312/ajax-error-err-insufficient-resources-how-to-avoid